# django.setup() in single file in 'apps' folder, got 'apps' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Solved by `sys.path.insert(0, project_root)` , I don't know the reason, if use `sys.path.append` will get this error.

---

Tried to create projects in apps folder, got error -- `'apps' is not a package`.

init project

```
django-admin startproject proj
cd proj
mkdir apps
cd apps
python ..\manage.py startapp foo
```

apps.py

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig
class FooConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.foo'
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
class FileModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='static/uploads')
```

settings.py

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'apps.foo',
]
```

python ..\manage.py makemigrations

python ..\manage.py migrate

tests.py

```
import os,sys

pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.relpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(pwd + "../../")
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

import django
django.setup()

# SomeModel.objects.create(xxxx)
```

$ proj\apps\foo>python tests.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\temp\delweb2\proj\apps\foo\tests.py", line 8, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\wgfabc\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.1\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\wgfabc\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\wgfabc\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 223, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\wgfabc\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1001, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps.foo'; 'apps' is not a package
```

Comment: You probably need to turn apps into a Python module by adding an `__init__.py` file to the folder

Comment: @Jimmy Pells , still not work, same error.

Comment: Is there a reason for you to use django.setup manually?

Comment: For saving unitest case result in database. I tried to use --keepdb, but not work. Trying to find some better solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to append an absolute path to sys.path and also a "/" would be missing in:

```
pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.relpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(pwd + "../../")
```

above code adds something like  "your_dir_name../../"

you could change it to

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```